# How to get the list of available publishes in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Similar to `Meteor.default_server.method_handlers` and `Meteor.connection._methodHandlers` which return lists of available methods on both server and client side. 
Is there a way to get such a list for Publishes?

Comment: I would really like to know your purpose behind getting all the list. why you would actually need that ? :) i will upvote your question if you explain me the fruitful purpose and impact :)

Comment: I want to dynamically create publishes from client by calling a server side method. But in this server side method that creates publishes , i need to know what are the currently available publishes otherwise it gives an error. Hope that is an interesting idea for you:)

Answer (score 2):

```
Meteor.default_connection._stores
```

And if you want to get the corresponding collection you can use, e.g.,

```
Meteor.default_connection._stores["publicationName"]._getCollection()
```

Comment: I think you can replace `Meteor.default_connection` by just `Meteor.connection`

Comment: Christian, I actually got it by Meteor.server.publish_handlers, but will try your solutions as well. thanks